# Data does not load into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

HTML file

```
<select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" id="superId" name="superId[]" multiple="multiple" required="required"
                                    data-bind="options: SupArray,
                                       optionsText: 'emp_display_name',
                                       value: supervisor,
                                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Javascript file

```
function UI() {

            var self = this;

            self.SupArray = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.EmployeeArray = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.emp = ko.observable("");
            self.supervisor = ko.observable("");
            self.startDate = ko.observable();
            self.endDate = ko.observable();


            self.emp.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                //  alert(ID);
                GetSupervisor(self.emp());

            });


        }



        var DisplayUI = new UI()
        ko.applyBindings(DisplayUI);



  function GetSupervisor(emp) {
          //  alert(emp.empId);
            var jsonData = ko.toJSON(DisplayUI);
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetSupervisorAll", "Registration")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                data:JSON.stringify({ empId: emp.empId}),
                success: function (data) {

             //   debugger;
                    DisplayUI.SupArray(data);
                    var abc = DisplayUI.SupArray();
                 //  alert(abc);
                    $('#superId').select2();

                }
             });
        }
```

Here when I load the supervisor back end data coming properly.

In ajax call data is coming up to success function.

When I debug this values are passed to the  "success: function (data)".

But values are did not append to the drop down.

```
success: function (data)
```

`console.log(data)`=>

[image]

Comment: Where is you append code , where are you appending data to select

Comment: In GetSupervisor() function. whithing the  success  in ajax call

Comment: My best guess is that `$('#superId').select2();` breaks knockout's connection with the DOM element. If you want to instantiate some sort of jQuery widget, you'll have to do it via a custom binding and make sure it is updated correctly.

Comment: I commented $('#superId').select2(); this. But data not coming

Comment: Are you sure that you don't call it upon initialization as well? If, after calling `ko.applyBindings`, you modify the DOM via any other way than a knockout binding, there's the risk of loosing your data-bind connection. It would help if you add a code snippet that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you're trying to make a multiple choise dropdown, shouldn't your observable then be an observableArray?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I have found the answer for this question.

```
 function GetSupervisor(emp) {
            //  alert(emp.empId);
            **if (emp != null) {**

                var jsonData = ko.toJSON(DisplayUI);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetSupervisorAll", "Registration")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data:JSON.stringify({ empId: emp.empId}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //  console.log(data);
                        //   debugger;
                        DisplayUI.SupArray(data);
                        var abc = DisplayUI.SupArray();
                        //  alert(abc);
                        $('#superId').select2();

                    }
                });
            }
```